# python random.choice in a class

Tags: python, class, random

I am trying to work on some code for something I am starting to make but I tested a short part of something important in my project and it doesn't seem to work as I want.
Here's the small segment of my code I tested:

```
class Fighter_Fish(object):   #class to manage all fishes and their stats
    fish_sum = 0

    def __init__(self,fish_name, fish_type, dice_list ,skill, trigger):
        self.fish_name = fish_name
        self.fish_type = fish_type
        self.dice_list = dice_list
        self.skill = skill
        self.trigger = trigger

    def dice_spin(self): #commences dice spin for current turn
        fish_sum = random.choice(self.dice_list)
        if fish_sum == "W":
           fish_sum = 0
           self.skill_commence()


clown_fish_list = ["1","2","2","2","3","3"]
clown_fish = Fighter_Fish("Clown_Fish","Def",clown_fish_list,"None","None")

clown_fish.dice_spin()
print (clown_fish.fish_sum)
```

The print should print one of the strings in from my tested list, but it returns 0

Am I using the class functions wrong?

Comment: Try `self.fish_sum = random.choice(self.dice_list` in `dice_spin()`.

Comment: Please correct the indentation to match the code you're actually running - are the last four lines inside the class definition?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The code I put here I didn't manage the indentation properly but fish_sum is a in the class and so are the 2 functions

Comment: OK, please confirm that @Andersson's edit matches what you're running

Answer (score 1):

Change `fish_sum` to `self.fish_sum` in `def dice_spin`.

Answer (score 0):

In your class, you have `fish_sum` defined as a class variable. When you run `dice_spin`, your class creates a *local variable* in your scope, also called `fish_sum`, but this does not refer to your class wide `fish_sum` variable.

As noted by DeepSpace, you can reference that var with `self`, but you might be better off not using a class wide variable, since it seems it is instance specific. To do that, instantiate it in `__init__` with `self`.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback :)

Comment: I tried it in the initiation function as you said and now it works perfectly thanks :)